# Architectural visualization

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, sculpting

I am intermediate in blender but I am new in architectural visualization. Can you help me with this?

How can I improve the first model to look like the second one? I need exactly the same look. I did it as I could but now I stuck and I need help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal or Cycles? Look closely at the reference image. You'll see a "pleat" where either the fabric has bee folded over or there might be separate panels added. Maybe google furniture construction. Also you'll notice lots of wrinkles. You may explore using some of the tools in "Sculpt Mode" to accomplish that. Make sure to make a duplicate of your original to work on in case you're not happy with the results you getting (I usually put one of the copies on a different layer).

Comment: Also, a fabric texture used as a bump map will hep add some of the fine detail that fabric has.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I use cycles. I will try to define pleats more. I made some wrinkles but it is even hard to see them. maybe I should use harder brush?

Comment: @ Mikhail Gavrilec - I don't have much experience with sculpting. You may want to create a separate question specifically on that topic. Also, If you look at the shadows on the floor caused by the end table you'll see how long they are. This dramatic "Side Lighting" helps to bring out detail in wrinkles etc. (The size of the light source also makes a difference).

Comment: Open ended, and opinion based questions don't really fit the format of this site.A forum format would be better. Try posting in blenderartists.org. There is a forum for focused critiques.  Please read this:  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the reference image. You'll see a "pleat" where either the fabric has bee folded over or there might be separate panels added. Maybe Google furniture construction. Also, you'll notice lots of wrinkles. You may explore using some of the tools in "Sculpt Mode" to accomplish that. Try some different tools and hardness until you are happy with the result. Make sure to make a duplicate of your original to work on in case you're not happy with the results you getting (I usually put one of the copies on a different layer).

In addition, If you look at the shadows on the floor caused by the end table you'll see how long they are. This dramatic "Side Lighting" helps to bring out detail in wrinkles etc. (The size of the light source also makes a difference).

Comment: I agree : more wrinkles, a bump or displacement texture (with openSubdiv surbsurf) to get the soft velvet effect and HDR lighting from the window + some interior soft light(s).